# What is this guitar?

Tags: electric-guitar, instruments

A few years back, I came across a guitar in the staging area of a pawn shop. I saw it, played it briefly, and bought it immediately after. I know nothing about it, but I'm hoping to gain some more knowledge about it by running it by the collective.

First things first - here's a picture:

[image]

This is what I know:

1. I believe the pickguard is nickel. There are four custom parts; the guard, the bridge cover, the plug cover, and a truss rod cover.
2. The body is swamp ash.
3. The neck is from a Peavey T-90 - however, it is clearly not a Peavey T-90.
4. It's a telecaster-style body

I think it is custom engraved - I haven't seen anything else like it ever (Teisco's from the 70s were close), but I'm hoping someone knows something about this that I don't. The engraving is absolutely stunning, and it really doesn't look like an amateur did it. Any information about value would be awesome as well. Is there anything I can look for to get more information about it?

Comment: Looks very good; I like the scratch plate a lot.  Whatever it is now it started out as a telecaster for sure.

Comment: Very difficult to tell. I'll research it though. I like challenges like this :D. Do you know if there was anything printed/engraved inside the neck pocket?

Comment: Jduv - it's been a while since I had the neck off, but I don't remember there being anything there. Would that indicate that it's not a Fender? If needed, I can take the neck off.

Answer (score 3):

I reckon that the Guitar is a Peavey Reactor Telecaster, probably a Reactor AX, because only they had the Swamp ash bodies, whereas the standard Reactor had a Poplar body. These guitars are quite cheap, and so a lot of people buy them and customise them up. I have been searching for the pickguard for sale for a bit now and I cannot find it anywhere, sadly, as it is awesome. I am particularly intrigued by the bridge pickup cover.

Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: Any idea on how to confirm that? Were they swamp ash?

Comment: Check my updated answer, the AX series were swamp ash, but the base model was not. :)

Comment: Very interesting information, thank you! One interesting detail though is that the pickup selector on the standard Reactor AX is completely different than this one. It could have been frankensteined together, but wouldn't you think the controls would have been left?

Comment: I noticed that, and it surprised me a little! How exactly does the selector work? Is it a dial or a lever, I can't really tell from the picture. These guitars are apparently great guitars to customize and mod, so I assume someone used this to experiment with. But if it works, then great! The pickups look fairly standard as well, are they?

Comment: The lipstick up top has awesome tone - I haven't disassembled it to check their make/manufacturer though. Here's the type of switch: http://img3.musiciansfriend.com/dbase/pics/products/2/9/4/431294.jpg

Comment: Oooh, yum. How does the guitar play/sound with that pickup cover?

Comment: It plays really, really well - but the bridge cover gets in the way, makes it really hard to palm mute.

Comment: Fair enough. Does it give the classic 'Tele' twang or something different?

Comment: I'm all in with Alistair. It's definitely a Reactor AX or some other type of Peavy Tele that's been hot rodded. There's nothing else on the market that looks like this. Definitely a custom job.

Comment: It's easy, and very common, to replace the control cover. My guess is someone didn't like the original selector switch. In addition to the neck pocket, some guitars have ID info under the pickguard, in the pickup holes, or in the wiring cavity. It just depends on the maker.

Comment: Well then - off goes the hardware to figure it out. I'll report back any findings.

Answer (score 0):

If you think that the neck isn't stock,and the pickguard doesn't seem to be, it is fully possible that it is a partocaster :) I am actually currently toying around with the idea of assembling a Strat from parts.